# Interbase 2020 crashes/loops

Tags: loops, crash, user-defined-functions, interbase, guardian

We use Interbase 2020 as production DB using UTF8 (approx 250 simultaneous user). With this database we have two main problems that we are not able to solve.

In history we had a problem with an older udf-function that crashed our database because it was not ready for unicode string operation. As a result we changed to unicode compatible versions.

The last few years sometimes we get hiccup (as we call it). In this case every client looses connection and the guardian restarts. The clients can connect again without us doing anything.

The second problem is that sometimes the interbase does not crash but everyone looses the connection and it is not possible to reconnect (by client, or ibexpert for example). In this case we have to restart the whole server.

These problems are occuring irregular. Most times it first starts with a hiccup. After a time (maybe two to ten hours later), the second problem arrives and we need to restart our database. If we are lucky we need to restart the server 2-3 times, on a bad day we need to restart the server more often as the second problem returns again and again (for example every 30 minutes).

We are not yet able to locate this problem. It doesn't matter if a user is connected to the database or just idling on weekends. It also often happens when nobody is connected.

Even the server logs don't give hints that helped us yet.

-We minimized udf function use as low as possible, changed to newer udfs that support unicode etc.
-functions that crash the server (afaik) are guarded that they dont get for example invalid datetimes
-We update database server regularely to newest version
-also updated client dlls
-also updated connection components (IBDAC) + Delphi 11.1
-wrote exception tracker in our client software (unfortunately there is only the connection lost error)
-regularely check active transactions if something hangs/loops/snapshot creation

Do you have any information that we could use to solve our problems? Is there any possibility to get more info out of the log files (other log levels possible?)? We don't want to log every procedure call if not necessary, but if there are no other options we need to..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Matze,

I suggest you log a Case with our Support team at Embarcadero (https://www.embarcadero.com/support). They will work with you to understand the specifics of the crash, get relevant details (and Performance Monitoring information) from you, and help us work on a resolution (if not addressed already in our latest update).

We have addressed a few corner cases (and other crash reports) in many updates over the past couple years in InterBase 2020, and are eager to get to the bottom of this issue as well. You can see some of the resolved crash reports at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Resolved_Defects

Supporting 250 simultaneous users is not the problem, but understanding how the use cases are running into any potential system resource limits is important.

You do mention that you have the latest updates to InterBase 2020, but I do not see a build number in your message. You can get the most recent update build (14.4.0.804) of the server (if on Windows) from https://my.embarcadero.com/#downloadDetail/1383